# Setting MaxReceivedMessageSize in the client of a wcf rest service

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have a rest WCF service to which I connect using a console application. The console app downloads a file. Small files work fine. For larger files I get the error below:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. 
To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element
```

This is my config file on the client side console app.

```
<configuration>     
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"
                  maxBufferSize="2000000">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The WCF config is as follows:

```
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyTestBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" transferMode="Buffered">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" maxStringContentLength="10000000" />
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
```

I am using WebChannelFactory to connect to the service. What could be wrong?

Comment: WCF support MaxRecivedMessageSize is 2147483647.You have to set it both side client and service.i like to see your WCF config settings

Comment: try adding a service behavior to your service config

Comment: Show the endpoints being used as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try assigning a name to the `webHttpBinding` in your client config file, and referencing it with the [WebChannelFactory Constructor (String, Uri)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908181.aspx).  This takes a string for the binding configuration name and the Uri of the service:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding name="MyWebHttpBinding">
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"
                 maxBufferSize="2000000">
```

`basicHttpBinding` is the default binding for `http`, so unless you've overridden that in the client config's `protocolMapping` section you will get the default values for `httpBinding`.

With the `name` attribute set, you could then get a factory instance like this:

```
WebChannelFactory<IContract> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IContract>("MyWebHttpBinding", new Uri("service address"));
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I had to provide a binding object when creating the factory instance. The string is an endpoint configuration name.

Comment: i am using c# wcf service in my java application in that where i configure this MaxBufferSize

Comment: @R.Anandan - That would be in the cofig for your Java client or in the code.  I suggest you post this as a new question with the relevant information.